# Java game select player class

Tags: java, class

I'm learning java by creating a game and i have :

```
public abstract class Char {
    private int hp;
    private int def;
    private int power;
    private int intelligence;
    privat1e int lvl;
    private int xp;

public void levelUp()
{
    lvl += 1;
    hp *= 2;
    def *= 2;
    power *= 2;
    intelligence *= 2;
}

public void basicalAttack(Char ennemy)
{
    ennemy.hp = ennemy.hp - (power - ennemy.def);
}

public int getHp() {
    return hp;
}
public void setHp(int hp) {
    this.hp = hp;
}
public int getDef() {
    return def;
}
public void setDef(int def) {
    this.def = def;
}
public int getPower() {
    return power;
}
public void setPower(int power) {
    this.power = power;
}
public int getIntelligence() {
    return intelligence;
}
public void setIntelligence(int intelligence) {
    this.intelligence = intelligence;
}
public int getLvl() {
    return lvl;
}
public void setLvl(int lvl) {
    this.lvl = lvl;
}
public int getXp() {
    return xp;
}
public void setXp(int xp) {
    this.xp = xp;
}

}
```

Then i have 2 class of characters :

```
public class Wizard extends Char {

public Wizard() {
    setLvl(1);
    setHp(400);
    setDef(150);
    setPower(20);
    setIntelligence(200);
}

public void fireBallAttack(Char ennemy)
{
    ennemy.setHp(ennemy.getHp() - (this.getIntelligence() + 20 - ennemy.getDef()));
}
}
```

and

```
public class Warrior extends Char {

public Warrior() {
    setLvl(1);
    setHp(1000);
    setDef(250);
    setPower(100);
    setIntelligence(20);
}

public void swordAttack(Char ennemy)
{
    ennemy.setHp(ennemy.getHp() - (this.getPower() + 10 - ennemy.getDef()));
}
}
```

So I want my playable Character to choose a class :

```
public class PlayableChar extends Char {
private String name;
private Char playable;
public PlayableChar(String name, String job) {
    this.setName(name);
    switch (job)
    {
        case "warrior" :
            setPlayable(new Warrior());
            break;
        case "Wizard" :
            setPlayable(new Wizard());
            break;
    }
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Char getPlayable() {
    return playable;
}
public void setPlayable(Char playable) {
    this.playable = playable;
}

}
```

So I ask to the user  which class he wants to use in my main  with

```
    Scanner readline = new Scanner(System.in);
    String jobName = "";
    String Name = "";
    System.out.print("Your name: ");
    Name = readline.nextLine();
    jobName = readline.nextLine();
    Playable mainChar = new Playable(Name, jobName);
```

Actually it works but when I want to use a method with `mainChar.getPlayable().fireBallAttack(ennemy)` it doesn't work and I get a

> fireBall(ennemy) is undefined for the Type Char;

Do I need to change my Warrior and Wizard classes ? or something else ? Thanks.

Comment: What is the `Playable` class ? Also, your `Char` class doesn't define any `fireBall` method .

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment, but you're supposed to spell it *enemy* not *ennemy*.

Comment: Cnsdr to not use abbrev. They m. the c. unrdbl.

Comment: The `Playable` class is for the main character. The player can choose between Warrior and Wizard but I don't know how to do it. The warrior has the `swordAttack` method and the Wizard the `fireBallAttack`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response and code, I assume there`s few typo`s and error`s in the question. I would like to point those out, before I provide the solution.

a)

```
Playable mainChar = new Playable(Name, jobName); should have been

PlayableChar mainChar = new PlayableChar (Name, jobName);  
//Note: Capitalisation is not recommended for variable names in java. 
//Referring to variable *Name* here
```

b) 
    Reference to fireBall(ennemy)  should have been fireBallAttack(ennemy).

You are narrow casting the playable attribute within PlayableChar class from Wizard / Warrior to Char class, when you call 
*mainChar.getPlayable().fireBallAttack(ennemy).* *mainChar.getPlayable().fireBallAttack(ennemy)* return a Char. At this stage compiler has no way of knowing if its Wizard / Warrior. It just knows, its a instance of Char class. The method *fireBallAttack(ennemy)* is defined only in Warrior class and not in Char class. This causes the compiler to throw the compile time error.

This is more of a design issue and there are multiple solutions to address this. The easiest one is to add the following two methods to Char class.

```
public void fireBallAttack(Char ennemy)
{

}

public void swordAttack(Char ennemy)
{

}
```

Comment: "Camel case is not recommended for variable names in java." What?

Comment: @dwjohnston  Was referring to variable  Name here. I have edited the response to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getHero()` (which isn't defined and you probably mean `getPlayable()`) returns a `Char`. Thus the compiler doesn't know the actual type (which could change at runtime) and thus doesn't know about the `fireBall()` method.

You could try and add an abstract method `attack(Char enemy)` to `Char` and implement it accordingly in `Wizard` and `Warrior`.

Besides that, games are quite a complex topic, so don't try to do too much if you're just learning the language. Start with simple things and expand on those. In a complex enough game composition would probably be a better way to go, i.e. the characters would get a set of behavior/skill classes which represent the type of attack etc. But I'd consider such a design out of scope for now (I just mentioned it to give a hint on how you could improve later, for a learner your design is actually quite good :) ).

Comment: Yes I meant `getPlayable()`, I want my Wizard not to have the same method as the Warrior so I don't think it would be with an abstract method in `Char`

Comment: @TerryRapt why not? You could still have a `fireBall(Char enemy)` method that  is called by `attack(Char enemy)`.